# Should this pointer created by "new" to be manually deleted after calling std::move()?

Tags: c++, pointers, move

I have a question about whether I should delete the pointer created by new in this situation.
I first create it, dereference it and move it to a new variable b. Will this address automatically delete by the destructor of the string by the instance b?

If we call it manually at the end of the main function, then what will happen when the destructor of b is called?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string* a = new string("Hello World");
    string b = move(*a);

    // Should we delete a the end or it is done by the destructor of b ???
    // delete a;
}
```

Comment: If you used `new`, you need to use `delete`.

Comment: there should be no `new`, hence no `delete` in *this situation*

Comment: @NathanOliver But if I use delete at the end. Then the destructor of "b" is working on an invalid address/instance that is already been deleted???

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have some special reason to use a pointer at some places. For example. pass the pointer from a union. Thus I cannot replace the pointer "string*" with simply a "string".

Comment: there is no "special reason to use `new` to construct a `std::string`". I you really need to dynamically allocate a `std::string` (and I doubt that) you should use a smart pointer and the matching `make_...` function but no `new`

Comment: After `*a` is moved-from, the remaining object is a hollowed out shell suitable for destruction.  And since it was `new`d, it needs to be `delete`d.  Note that a `string` is already a smart pointer (specializing in string manipulation), so it really makes no sense to `new` a string.  But I presume that was just being used for example.

Comment: @AltmanJeffry There is no issue.  `b` holds the contests of the string, so it will handle it correctly.  What delete needs to do is free up the memory that `a` still points to.

Comment: You should not be creating a pointer in the first place. Move semantics has kind of been designed to NOT have to use pointers to manage resources and fully rely on the lifecycle of objects as defined by scopes. You might want to read up on RAII

Comment: Not only free up the memory. After `string b = move(*a);`, `*a` is still an existing object and its destructor needs to be called (prior to freeing its storage).

Comment: Re: “the destructor of "b" is working on an invalid address/instance” — moving from an object of a type defined in the standard library leaves the object in a **valid** but unspecified state. If it didn’t, moving from an object on the stack would be a disaster, because the destructor runs automatically when the name goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: What you create via `new` you must `delete` or there'll be a memory leak.

---

After moving from the string, the string is still alive. As anything constructed via `new` it has to be destroyed via `delete`.

However, you should not use `new` in the first place to construct a `std::string`. `std::string` does already manage its dynamically allocated memory.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string a{"Hello World"};
    string b = move(a);
}
```

Here, both `a`s and `b`s destructor is called when `main` returns.

If you do need to dynamically allocate the string (I doubt it) you should use a smart pointer rather than manual `new` and `delete`.

---

Some pedantry on wording...

You do not "create a pointer via `new`". You construct a string and `a` points to that string. `delete a;` deletes the string not the pointer. It is important to not confuse the pointer and the pointee.

`std::move` itself does not move anything. Its the move constructor of `std::string` that does the move (and `std::move` is just needed to signal that `*a` is no longer needed and can be moved from). It is important to not confuse `std::move` with the actual act of moving. The name is unfortunate, as `std::move` is merely a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string),

> (8) Move constructor. Constructs the string with the contents of `other` using move semantics. `other` is left in valid, but unspecified state.

Still, you need to manually delete the pointer to reclaim the memory space used by the string in a valid but unspecified state.